# Как добавить дополнительное слово с помощью xml.Serializer

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Необходимо, чтобы при сериализации кода происходила сериализация вида, как указано ниже. Не могу найти, как добавить "name" перед First и чтобы Last было следующим с помощью Xml.Serializer. Подскажите какую конструкцию использовать, или укажите где прочитать с какой-то конкретикой.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.cpandl.com">
        <mail id="1">
                <name First="Teresa" Last = "Atkinson" />
                <Line1>1 Main St.</Line1>
                <City>AnyTown</City>
                <State>WA</State>
                <Zip>00000</Zip>
        </mail>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: Порядок атрибутов и элементов в коллекции не является критическим для сериализации или десереализации. Элементы и атрибуты могут следовать в любом порядке. Значение имеет только положение элемента в дереве относительно родителя и его состав атрибутов, но не порядок. Поэтому вы хотите странного. Или я не понял вопроса. Также покажите C# модель данных, которую вы используете для сериализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("PurchaseOrder", Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Address mail;
}

public class Address
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string id;
    public Name name;
    public string Line1;
    public string City;
    public string State;
    public string Zip;
}

public class Name
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string First;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Last;
}
```

Добавил класс Name с указанием сериализовать в атрибуты. Если нужен код инициализации, сериализации и вывода xml на экран, я добавлю его.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось, оказывается все было просто. Инициализация и сериализация у меня уже была написана.

Answer (score 0):

name- это класс, в нем 2 public string First и Last. Здесь не должно быть никаких проблем.